# How to add android application to setting system?

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

We built iris recognition application for android when user open his phone the our application should be starting.
My question How can add our application to setting-->Security-->change screen lock in android and android open by the our application not by password or pattern? 
I searched about that and I didn't find anything useful ?

Thanks

Comment: Create your own ROM mod with your own modified version of the Settings app and the lockscreen that integrates your technology.

Comment: @CommonsWare what's mean ROM mod and how can I create it ?

Comment: @CommonsWare Are mean like this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195858 ?

Comment: Yes, "ROM mod" is [an alternative firmware for an Android device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_custom_Android_firmwares).